# Django não cria tabelas

Tags: django, django-templates

Saudações a todos.
Estou com problemas para criar as tabelas para minhas apps pelo Django. Rodo o comando PYTHON MANAGE.PY MAKEMIGRATIONS e ele responde: NO CHANGES DETECTED. Em seguida rodo o comando PYTHON MANAGE.PY MIGRATE e ele responde: NO MIGRATIONS TO APPLY.

Simplesmente não está criando as tabelas que preciso.

O que eu já tentei:

- Excluir as tabelas do Django no banco de dados;
- Apagar o banco de dados e recriá-lo usando o MySQL Workbench.

Meu código em models.py:

```
class Cliente(models.Model):
    nome     = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug_c   = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    cpf_cnpj = models.CharField(verbose_name="CPF/CNPJ", max_length=18, unique=True)
    email    = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    fone     = models.CharField(verbose_name="Telefone fixo", max_length=25, blank=True)
    celular  = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    endereco = models.CharField(verbose_name="Endereço", max_length=200, blank=True)
    numero   = models.CharField(verbose_name="nº", max_length=7, blank=True)
    compl    = models.CharField(verbose_name="Complemento", max_length=50, blank=True)
    bairro   = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True)
    cidade   = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    estado   = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)
    cep      = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    objects = ClienteMan()
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Clientes"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

class Obra(models.Model):
    nomeid    = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, to_field="nome", verbose_name="ID Cliente", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    titulo    = models.CharField(verbose_name="Título", max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug_o    = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    tipo_obra = models.CharField(verbose_name="Tipo de obra", max_length=50)
    endereco  = models.CharField(verbose_name="Endereço", max_length=200)
    numero    = models.CharField(verbose_name="nº", max_length=7)
    compl     = models.CharField(verbose_name="Complemento", max_length=50, blank=True)
    bairro    = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    cidade    = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    estado    = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    cep       = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    obs       = models.TextField(verbose_name="observações", blank=True)
    objects = ObraMan()
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Obras"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo

class Diario(models.Model):
    obraid    = models.ForeignKey(Obra, verbose_name="Obra", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    data      = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False)
    slug_d    = models.SlugField(blank=True, unique=True)
    imagem    = models.ImageField(upload_to='diarios/', null=True, blank=True)
    arquivo   = models.FileField(upload_to='diarios/', null=True, blank=True)
    descricao = models.TextField(verbose_name="descrição", blank=True)
    objects = DiarioMan()
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Diário"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.data.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Desde já agradeço imensamente a sua ajuda.

Comment: Para resolver este problema, remova o conteúdo da pasta `migrations` deixando apenas o arquivo `__init__.py`. Para cada um dos apps que está com este problema. Não executar este procedimento em produção.

Comment: Pasta *migrations* da aplicação está vazia. Tentei rodar novamente os comandos e o problema persiste.

Comment: Esse é o problema, tem que ter o arquivo `__init__.py`

Comment: DEU CERTO!!! Muito obrigado plea sua ajuda! Eu criei um arquivo em branco com o nome de `__init__.py` dentro da pasta `migrations` da minha app e rodei novamente os comandos makemigrations e depois migrate. Funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesta solução estou supondo que não existe problema em apagar o banco de dados, desta forma uma maneira de resolver o problema é:

- remover o conteúdo da pasta `migrations` que está dentro de cada app, deixando apenas o arquivo `__init__.py`
- Se não houver arquivos dentro da pasta `migrations` será necessário criar apenas o arquivo `__init__.py`
- Caso utilize um Sistema Operacional baseado em Unix, estando na pasta `migrations`, basta o comando :

  ```
    touch __init__.py
  ```

Caso tenha muitos `apps` em seu projeto o mesmo efeito pode ser conseguido estando no mesmo local do arquivo manage.py e executando o seguinte comando:

```
find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete
find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete
```

Após executar estes passos basta fazer o drop do banco de dados ou apagar o arquivo:  `db.sqlite3`.

Agora será possível gerar uma nova migrations e aplicar as alterações das migrations criadas, utilizando o comando:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Para outros métodos, basta consultar o [tutorial do Victor Freitas](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html)

Answer (score 0):

Se anteriormente tu fez um makemigrations e depois o migrate dentro da pasta que possui o model Cliente a outra pasta chamada "migrations"

```
A pasta migrations: 
Deve estar com arquivos python chamado 
0001_initial.py
0002_initial.py 
0003_initial.py  esses são como um referencia de modificação para comparação 
de migrations.
Python pode não ter reconhecido mudanças usando como referencia esses 
arquivos gerados.
Pode apagar todos exceto o arquivo python chamado "__init__.py"
E utilizar novamente a instrução makemigrations e depois o migrate.
Supondo que já excluio o banco de dados e as instruções não modificou
o que queria.
```